# Is Wald statistic sufficient to show no association?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-strategies

When reporting the results of multivariable regression analyses, I would normally provide either $\beta$ with 95% confidence interval, or the estimated effect size (e.g. between Q1 and Q3). However, this seems to be misleading to some readers - e.g. $\beta = 0.9 (-0.2; 2.0)$ could be interpreted as a positive association, just not statistically significant. Unfortunately there is a tendency in my field to ignore the uncertainty of an estimate and use colourful language (trending towards significance, suggestive of a significant effect) to find an effect where there is none. I would like to avoid this by providing such data only in the supplement - and use e.g. a Wald statistic in the main text.

Would it be appropriate to provide the result of the Wald test (e.g. given by  `anova.rms` for individual covariables)? Using the p-value for the regression coefficients is not possible, as after transformation to splines there are multiple values.

Comment: How about you include the coefficient p-value?

Comment: Could you clarify the sense in which you think "positive association, just not statistically significant" would be a misleading interpretation?

Comment: You could consider a graphical display that emphasizes the uncertainty over the point estimate (e.g. shaded line with darker color around estimate). I think Spiegelhalter gave some nice presentations on how to communicate uncertainty.